# Want to delete the text from the JAVA Edit and update a new value in that

Tags: scripting, vbscript, qtp

I want to delete the text present in the Java Edit box and want to add a new Text into that feild.

How can i perform this task in QTP (Scripting)?

Answer (score 2):

@TestGeek

If you want to use "ctl+A and delete" sequence, use *.Type()* method of *Edit* object.
If your object is not fully supported by QTP and does not have *.Type()* method, you can use *WshShell.SendKeys()* as a workaround (don't forget to set focus on the object first).

In QTP, constants are defined with "mic" (Mercury Integer Constant) prefix. You can search for the full list in help.

For those, that you mentioned, you need the following:
**micCtrlDwn**
"A"
**micCtrlUp**
**micDel**

Answer (score 2):

Try using the objects native function `setText("")`. This resets the contents to an empty string. The advantage is that is does the job in 1 line.

The `.object` allows access to the native methods, and a tooltip with all methods will appear in the qtp IDE only if the UI object is actually open on the screen.

```
JavaWindow("win").JavaInternalFrame("frame").JavaEdit("edit").Object.setText("")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with the Java add in but AFAIK the `Set` method replaces the text. If you really need to clear it first you can set to the empty string.

```
 JavaWindow("win").JavaEdit("box").Set "" ''# Clear old text (optional)
 JavaWindow("win").JavaEdit("box").Set "new value"
```

Comment: No this will not work correctly in all times, Becoz if the Content is having White spaces or anything such than it will not work. I guess something like ctl+A and delete operation i want to perform. How can i achieve this in QTP or VB?